# eye target controller is not visible in CG Cookie Flex Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I've been trying to test out the CG Cookie Flex Rig, but i faced a problem when i got to the face controllers. i can select the eye target controller but it's not visible on the 3D view. are there any possible ways to show the controller? it would be very annoying during the animation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mine is visible, try to check the "hide" button or download the file from another site.

[image]

Comment: The Outliner on his image shows that is not hidden, the eye is open.

Comment: Check the scale under custom shape.